# Trouble Installing Mac Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've tried the various forums and teh Google to no avail. I'm trying to install Mac Homebrew on OS X 10.6.8. When I try the install command from the Homebrew Homepage:

```
ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

I get the following errors:

```
host-197-7-0-10:~ rzazueta$ ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press enter to continue
==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew...
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew    /info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n
```

That 403 is rather odd. Any idea what could be happening here? I was able to successfully install using this method on another Mac, so I feel confident the issue is on my machine, but I don't even know where to begin to figure out what's causing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Check their installation page ([https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew)) and look under alternate installs.

The pertinent line being:

```
cd /usr/local/bin    
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

then just

```
ln -s path/to/homebrew/bin/brew /usr/local/bin/brew
```

I think the path listed on [Link](https://brew.sh/) is dated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on OS X 10.8.2. It turned out that I had an old version of git (1.6.5.2) installed in /usr/local. When I removed that and used the version provided with Mountain Lion (1.7.10.2), the normal install worked fine.

Comment: I had this problem as well. Moving the old git out of the way cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

Just installed using:

```
ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

and it work without problems.
Maybe it was a *temporary* problem...

Comment: Nope, still not working. I believe I've traced it back to the fact that I'm still on Snow Leopard. Planning to upgrade, then will try it again.

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary Github problem. It happens occasionally. Try again later.

Answer (score 0):

Carefull, the install script has moved from raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go to raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install !

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

instead of ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)

Comment: the above doesn't work anymore. try ```ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above answers but they din't work.Then I found maybe the link was broken. I use the following command and succeed:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```