# Error installing mac homebrew

Tags: installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install homebrew for mac. As per the easy homebrew install method I entered:

```
plpxdc1:~ lpxdc1$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get the following error, however:

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I realise that there has been a fairly similar question asked on this ([Trouble Installing Mac Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355771/trouble-installing-mac-homebrew), and I've tried following the fixes on there and still no joy. Is there a way to establish where the error is occurring? Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: I've tried turning both off and still get the same issue